# Classloader.getResources() in maven project returns an empty Enumeration

Tags: java, maven, classloader

I have some code which gets resources as follows:

```
public static final String CONVERTER_FILE = "META-INF/jumbo-converters";
static {
        ClassLoader ldr = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        Enumeration<URL> e = ldr.getResources(CONVERTER_FILE);
```

but when I run this in a JUnit test (Java 6) the enumeration is empty. There are a number of subprojects in the project which have the following file:

```
myProject/mySubProject/src/main/resources/META-INF/jumbo-converters
```

and I believe that it has worked in the past. What does `getResources` do? and how can I debug its current failure?

Comment: Maybe src/main/resources doesn't automatically merges with src/test/resources. So you need write in your pom.xml (<testResources><resource>src/main/resources</resource></testResources>

Comment: Updated answer as I misread your question the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resources for a module (sub-project) will not be added to the classpath of the aggregating project unless the aggregating project has a dependency on the module. Being a module to a project does not establish a dependency relationship in either direction.

In your case above you should add a dependency on mySubProject to myProject. Thus making myProject depend on mySubProject.

Comment: Thanks. This is the strategy that was intended and it now works for me

Comment: Project relationships can get kinda crazy in maven as you can have a project A that aggregates a module B that has a parent project C which has no modules at all. The parent-child relationship, aggregator-module relationship and dependent-dependency relationship are all orthogonal concepts in maven project structure.

Answer (score 2):

To load the file using `ClassLoader.getResources()` it has to be found on your classpath. The solution would be to make sure that the parent folder to `META-INF` is in the classpath.

Comment: does not ../src/main/resources automatically put this on the classpath?

Comment: @peter.murray.rust, if the `resources` folder is on the classpath, the file would be found (if it is readable by the curent user) if you use a relative path, maybe the test is not started from a sub-folder of `mySubProject`? Can you try using an absolute path instead?